# How to check if a non-renewable receipt is expired (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app

I have a free iOS app that have some "pro" feature that can be enabled for 1 year with a non-renewable subscription.
I can't find a good solution to test if the license is expired or not. 
I have the receipt with the purchase Date.
My first approach was pretty basic date comparison with the current time ([NSDate date]). 
But this value change if the user change the device Date Time, this is pretty dumb.

Is there any way to test the expiration of this kind of license without using internet connection?

Answer (score -1):

You could always store the value for the date 1 year from the purchase and check against that, and update that date if it is renewed.

Comment: From the question: "My first approach was pretty basic date comparison with the current time ([NSDate date]). But this value change if the user change the device Date Time, this is pretty dumb."

Comment: i know that, but if you store the date the purchased the licence and a year from that in a database, or even the plist and compare the two concrete dates at all times, you don't have to worry about the changing the system date and time.

Comment: The problem is that I can't have a trustworty date to test my stored date. I can save any date I want, but I need a real date to test this value with.

Comment: ok i see, its going to be hard, when you don't want to check using the internet.